# Sending form using Ajax with 2 submit buttons sends value of both buttons. Is there a way to prevent it?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, submit

So, I have a form which uses Ajax to send data.
It collects all data using .serialize(), and sends it to a PHP script.
It works perfectly, apart from the moment when I use 2 different submit buttons to trigger different actions.
I mean, I have such code in the PHP script:

```
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
....
}
if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
....
}
```

And when you click a button once, it works fine, but afterwards when you press another button it sends both buttons in a POST array. So I wonder is there a way to prevent it?
Tried to disable the one button after clicking on another, tried .reset() JQuery function - it doesn't work.

Comment: It is a client side issue. As you have not shared js code, we can only guess what is happening. Most probably js is keeping the previous serialised values in a variable and the second button press is adding more parameters to the same variable. Try resetting the variable after you post the data via ajax.

Comment: Unfortunetely, I declare the variable directly in the submit function in this way:
var formData = $(this).serialize();
So there is no way for JS script to save the old form data.

Comment: Suggest you add minimal  js code to the question such that the issue is reproducible. Then someone can help.

Comment: !SOLVED. Figured out myself. Just made buttons with the same name, but values are different. And when you submit a form using these buttons, just check which one value was submited and that's it.